# Java SWT: show paintings in tooltip

Tags: java, image, swt, tooltip

I want to set tooltip for StyledText in Java SWT. The idea is to show information for the text where the mouse clicks. Up to now I can only show text in the tooltip, but I want the whole tooltip to be an image, which is painted using drawing methods in SWT to show some structure in the information. It seems Tooltip won't handle that, so could anyone suggest me how to do that, or with which widget I can achieve it?

Edit: How can I set the size of the composite which `createToolTipContentArea` returns?

```
protected Composite createToolTipContentArea(Event event, Composite parent) {
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
composite.addPaintListener(new SPPaintListener());
composite.setSize(680, 600);

return composite;
}
private class SPPaintListener implements PaintListener {

public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {

  drawLyrics(e);
  e.gc.dispose();
}
}

private void drawLyrics(PaintEvent e) {
e.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);

Font font = new Font(e.display, "Purisa", 10, SWT.NORMAL);
Color color = new Color(e.display, 25, 25, 25);

e.gc.setForeground(color);
e.gc.setFont(font);

e.gc.drawText("em so transitory", 20, 30);
e.gc.drawText("em so transitory", 180, 30);
e.gc.drawText("Theermanent one", 20, 60);
e.gc.drawText("Theermanent one", 180, 60);

e.gc.drawLine(10, 30, 15, 30);

font.dispose();
}
```

like said, I need some paintings on the composite, but they won't get shown fully.

Comment: The JFace `ToolTip` class can do this if you are not restricted to just SWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a class derived from `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip` to draw anything you like in a tooltip.

```
public class MyToolTip extends ToolTip
{
  public MyToolTip(Control control)
  {
    super(control, NO_RECREATE, false);
  }

  @Override
  protected Composite createToolTipContentArea(final Event event, final Composite parent)
  {
    // TODO add your controls here
  }
}
```

Use with:

```
new MyToolTip(control);
```

where `control` is the control that should have the tooltip.

I have shown the simplest form where the tooltip area is the same for the whole control. You can also override the `getToolTipArea` method to change the tooltip depending on the position in the control.

For an image the createToolTopArea might look like:

```
@Override
protected Composite createToolTipContentArea(final Event event, final Composite parent)
{
  Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

  body.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  Label label = new Label(body, SWT.LEAD);

  Image image = ... your image

  label.setImage(image);

  return body;
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for answering, that should suit my requirement but just one question: how can I set the size of the tooltip? I tried it and it seems that the size is automatically calculated based on the text it displays. But I need to display a composite with drawing on it, and I can get only part of it displayed.

Comment: I have added an example with an example, adapted from code I use

Comment: Yes I used it already, but I still can't set the size of the composite. see my updated post.

Comment: I haven't tried anything like that. You maybe want a child Canvas of the main Composite. With GridLayout on the main composite you can use GridData for the LayoutData of the child and can specify the widthHint and heightHint values.